# Perl sftp downloads with Net::SFTP::Foreign

Tags: perl

Im a beginner. I have written a perl script which does the following

-Create a directory under “/x01/abcd/abc_logs/abcd_Logs” by the current date, in the format of “YYYYMMDD” if it has not already been created.
i.e:  if the script is run on “01st of jan 2013”, the directory “20130101” will be created under the said path. So whenever there is a need to inspect the logs always look for a directory by the current date.

-Check if the log file(s) have already been downloaded earlier within the same day, and  if not log(s) will be downloaded to the TODAY’s directory.

Im having a hard time, coming up with a solution to print a message when there are no files in the share. This is of course when the user specify 2 or more files that are not there in the share. I know that this happens because there is a "die" statement in the "sub get_LOGS". I just cannot seem to understand how to return a message when all the files I specify do not happen to be in the share.

usage of this script is as follows

./abc_logs  ....<file(n)>

following is the script.

```
my $LOGS_LOCAL_PATH = "/x02/abc/abcba2/";
chomp $LOGS_LOCAL_PATH;
my $LOGS_REM_PATH = "/x01/INT/abc/vabc2/";
chomp $LOGS_REM_PATH;
my $TODAY = `date +%Y%m%d`;
chomp $TODAY;
my @GETLOOP = @ARGV;
    unless ($#ARGV >= 0) {
        print "\nUsage: gtp_logs.pl <file1> <file2> <file3>.....<file(n)>\n\n";
        exit;
    }
        system("clear");
    unless ( -d "$LOGS_LOCAL_PATH"."$TODAY") {
        print "Directory \"$TODAY\" doesn't exist. So creating the directory..!\n";
        print "OK..Done.....!\n\n";
        system("mkdir $LOGS_LOCAL_PATH/$TODAY");
        }
    else {
        print "Directory already exists. Logs will be downloaded to ==>     \"$LOGS_LOCAL_PATH$TODAY\".....!\n\n";
    }
    
               # if_DOWNLOADED($LOGS_LOCAL_PATH,$TODAY,@GETLOOP);
    
    chdir("$LOGS_LOCAL_PATH"."$TODAY") || die "cannot cd to  ($!)";
    foreach my $GETL (@GETLOOP) {
    my $is_downloaded = if_DOWNLOADED($LOGS_LOCAL_PATH,$TODAY,$GETL);
    if(!$is_downloaded)
    {
        get_LOGS("172.25.70.221","abc","abc2","/x01/INT/abc",$GETL);
        print "File \"$GETL\" downloaded to ==>          \"$LOGS_LOCAL_PATH$TODAY\"\n\n";
    }
    else
    {
        print "File \"$GETL\" has already been Downloaded to ==>          \"$LOGS_LOCAL_PATH$TODAY\"\n\n";
    }
    
    
    }
    

 sub get_LOGS {
    my $LOG_HOST  = shift;
    my $REM_USER  = shift;
    my $REM_PASSW = shift;
    my $REM_PATH  = shift;
    my $REM_FILE  = shift;
    
        print "Connecting to the sftp share! Please wait....!\n";
        my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new($LOG_HOST, user => $REM_USER, password => $REM_PASSW);
        $sftp->setcwd($REM_PATH) or die "unable to change cwd: " . $sftp->error;
        print "OK. On the share! Downloading the file \"$REM_FILE\"...................!\n\n\n\n";
        $sftp->error and die "Problem connecting to the share...!!!! " . $sftp->error;
        $sftp->get($REM_FILE) or die "File does not seem to be present on the remote share. Please re-request..!!!" . $sftp->error;
        return $REM_FILE;
}
   
sub if_DOWNLOADED {
    my $DWD_FILE_PATH = shift;
    my $DWD_DIR       = shift;
    my $DWD_FILE      = shift;
    if (-e "$DWD_FILE_PATH/$DWD_DIR/$DWD_FILE")
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Please can someone help me finding a solution to this matter? Please try to use the same script and modify.

/V

Comment: Please, don't use `unless ... else` construction.

Answer (score 3):

Some comments to your code:

- Use strict and warnings in order to catch lots of errors early.
- Read some book on style (i.e. Damian Conway's Perl Best Practices). But in any case try to be consistent when naming variables, subroutines, and everything and also with their case.
- When you have to use some calculated value in several places, try to calculate it once and save it in a variable.
- Don't use subroutines for trivial things.
- You don't need to call `chomp` on variables you have defined and that don't have a `"\n"` character at the end.
- Opening a new SFTP connection for every file transfer is very inefficient. You can open just one at the beginning and use it for all the transfers.

And now, a simplified version of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $host = "172.25.70.221";
my $user = "abc";
my $password = "abc1234321";

my $LOGS_LOCAL_PATH = "/x02/ABC/abc2";
my $LOGS_REM_PATH = "/x01/INT/abc/vim";
my $TODAY = `date +%Y%m%d`;
chomp $TODAY;
my $TODAY_LOCAL_PATH = "$LOGS_LOCAL_PATH/$TODAY";

my @files = @ARGV;
@files or die "\nUsage: gtp_logs.pl <file1> <file2> <file3>.....<file(n)>\n\n";

system("clear");

if ( -d $TODAY_LOCAL_PATH) {
    print "Directory already exists. Logs will be downloaded to ==>     \"$TODAY_LOCAL_PATH\".....!\n\n";
}
else {
    print "Directory \"$TODAY\" doesn't exist. So creating the directory..!\n";
    mkdir "$TODAY_LOCAL_PATH" or die "unable to create directory: $!\n";
    print "OK..Done.....!\n\n";
}

chdir $TODAY_LOCAL_PATH or die "cannot cd to  ($!)\n";

my $sftp =  Net::SFTP::Foreign->new($host, user => $user, password => $password);
$sftp->error
    and die "Problem connecting to the share...!!!! " . $sftp->error;

my $ok = 0;
my $failed = 0;
foreach my $file (@files) {
    if (-e "$TODAY_LOCAL_PATH/$file") {
        print "File \"$file\" has already been Downloaded to ==>          \"$TODAY_LOCAL_PATH\"\n";
    }
    else {
        if ($sftp->get("$LOGS_REM_PATH/$file")) {
            print "File \"$file\" downloaded to ==>          \"$TODAY_LOCAL_PATH\"\n";
            $ok++;
        }
        else {
            print "Unable to download file \"$file\" : " . $sftp->error . "\n";
            $failed++;
        }
    }
}

print "$ok files have been downloaded, $failed files failed!\n\n";
```